# How to create a Spring Integration pipeline connecting jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter and jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I want to write a sample application to create a copy table

My config is as below
As a step1 : I tested inbound channel adapter to write to jdbcMessageHandler. This is OK

Step 2: Connect outbound to inbound. The below is about this step.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd">

<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="dataChannel"
    query="select * from articles where sent = 0" 
    update="update articles set sent = 1 where id in (:id)"
    data-source="dataSource" row-mapper="articleRowMapper">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


<!-- <int:service-activator input-channel="dataChannel" ref="jdbcMessageHandler" /> 
<bean id="jdbcMessageHandler" class="com.demo.service.JdbcMessageHandler" /> -->


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="10000" />

<int:channel id="dataChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="demo" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="articleRowMapper" class="com.demo.domain.ArticleRowMapper" />

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcOutbound"
                                       channel="dataChannel"
                                       data-source="dataSource"
                                       sql-parameter-source-factory="sqlParameterSource"
                                       query="INSERT INTO ARTICLES(ID, NAME, CATEGORY , TAGS , AUTHOR , SENT) VALUES(:id, :name, :category,:tags,:author,:sent)"/>
    <bean id="sqlParameterSource"   class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
        <property name="parameterExpressions">
            <map>
                <entry key="id" value="payload.id"/>
                <entry key="name" value="payload.name"/>
                <entry key="category" value="payload.category"/>
                <entry key="tags" value="payload.tags"/>
                <entry key="author" value="payload.author"/>
                <entry key="sent" value="payload.sent"/>                    
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Error:

> SEVERE: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error
> occurred in message handler
> [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler#0]; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO ARTICLES(ID, NAME,
> CATEGORY , TAGS , AUTHOR , SENT) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?,?,?)Invalid argument
> value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value:
> java.io.NotSerializableException, failedMessage=GenericMessage
> [payload=[com.demo.domain.Article@49023a31,
> com.demo.domain.Article@2d25f418, com.demo.domain.Article@31d44fe8],
> headers={id=1c16e823-b70e-faf1-2ea5-5475e3f8dbde,
> timestamp=1661550341366}]     at
> org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:153)

I presume a **list** is coming from inbound, and it needs to be handled properly by outbound (which is expecting only 1 message ?)

How to manage this - list ?

I am using the same *dataChannel*, which I want to avoid. (have more loose coupling). What can I do to achieve this ?

thanks

Comment: One note - I have a clob column also, so lookig at Using the PreparedStatement Callback section of https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html   but not sure how to do it using xml

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you use the latest Spring Integration version. The batch update support was added long time ago: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#batch-update. You also can add a `splitter` in between to insert one by one. I believe that most drivers map a string parameter to CLOB properly , so we might not need a `PrepareDStatementSetter` feature. Although you still can have via a `prepared-statement-setter` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @artembilan Is there an example for xml. config. I see documentation on clob ps.setClob(3, new StringReader(m.getHeaders().get("description", String.class))); But I want to see how to use an adapter (not gateway) and prepared statement. I dont know how to use batch or splitter. So please give example

Comment: When I used jdbcmessagehandler , the bean was handling public void handleMessage(List<Article> articleList) {  NOT Message. How can splitter help me here ? If splitter does something like  (List)message.getPayload() to convert message to list<myType>. So please can you help me with an example

Comment: I think you need to start with this book: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ to understand what is message , payload, channel and so on until the splitter and its functionality. What you are asking has to work out-of-the-box . The CLOB question should be separate . You may exclude a CLOB from the current iteration to be sure that batch insert works first of all

Comment: I do not know what made you think I need to understand Message, Payload , Channel, when I already told Step1 works? The error message says the message is GenericMessage [payload=[com.demo.domain.Article@49023a31, com.demo.domain.Article@2d25f418, com.demo.domain.Article@31d44fe8] , which tells me that a list of objects are in a  Generic Message Wrapper.  You suggested splitter and all I am asking a few lines on how , If that is a solution

Comment: The splitter goal is to divide a payload of incoming message to smaller chunks . Form a message per chunk and produce it to output channel. By default splitter deals with collections naturally: every item of that is produced as an individual messages. So, the piece of code for you there is just this `<int:splitter/>` with respective channels configuration. All of that is explained in Spring Integration docs. But since you have asked me a fundamental question about payload and splitter I made an assumption that you are not well with EIP theory yet. Sorry for misunderstanding than.

Comment: I am actually struggling (and confused) hence looking for an answer. I do not know where to put the splitter <int:splitter/>.  I am trying whatever I can Example: <bean id="articleSplitterBean" class="com.demo.service.SplitterService"/>
<int:splitter id="testSplitter" input-channel="dataChannel" ref="articleSplitterBean" output-channel="outChannel">
</int:splitter>. Now should I create splitter like ordinary class or use extend AbstractMessageSplitter (tried this method) . Is any toString required ? Issue seems to be with jdbc outbound channel adapter. "Invalid argument value"

Comment: Sorted. one of the column is passed null because the Pojo has no sent column , where as the database has. I will post complete answer, if ok

Comment: Good to hear that you have figured out JDBC issue! But did you get it the stuff with that splitter? You may place it just before your JDBC channel adapter . Not clear though why do you need a custom one since you have only a collection in the payload to split it simply with a default one…

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ArtemBilan for your splitter suggestion

Note: There is scope for refactoring, but this is just a Poc

My config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd">
            
<int:channel id="testchannel"/>
    
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="testchannel" method="produce"  ref="producer">        
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="producer" class="com.demo.Producer"/>


<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcOutboundCreator" 
                                   channel="testchannel"                                           
                                   data-source="dataSource"
                                   sql-parameter-source-factory="sqlParameterSource2"
                                   query="INSERT INTO articleslob(ID, NAME, CATEGORY , TAGS , AUTHOR , sent, msg ) VALUES(:id, :name, :category,:tags,:author,:sent,:msg)"
                                   
                                   />
<bean id="sqlParameterSource2"   class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="id" value="payload.id"/>
            <entry key="name" value="payload.name"/>
            <entry key="category" value="payload.category"/>
            <entry key="tags" value="payload.tags"/>
            <entry key="author" value="payload.author"/>
            <entry key="sent" value="payload.sent"/>
            <entry key="msg" value="payload.msg" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
    
<!-- <entry key="msg" value="new org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.SqlLobValue(payload.msg)" /> -->
<int:channel id="inProgressChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="inProgressChannel"
    query="select * from articleslob where sent = 0" 
    update="update articleslob set sent = 1 where id in (:id)"
    data-source="dataSource" row-mapper="articleRowMapper">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="100">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="1000" />



<bean id="articleSplitterBean" class="com.demo.service.SplitterService"/>
<int:splitter id="testSplitter" input-channel="inProgressChannel" ref="articleSplitterBean" output-channel="outChannel">
</int:splitter>

<int:channel id="outChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="demo" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="articleRowMapper" class="com.demo.domain.ArticleRowMapper" />


 
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcOutbound"    
                                       channel="outChannel"                                        
                                       data-source="dataSource"
                                       sql-parameter-source-factory="sqlParameterSource"
                                       query="INSERT INTO articlescopy(ID, NAME, CATEGORY , TAGS , AUTHOR , sent , msg ) VALUES(:id, :name, :category,:tags,:author,:sent , :msg)"
                                       />
<bean id="sqlParameterSource"   class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <property name="parameterExpressions">
        <map>
            <entry key="id" value="payload.id"/>
            <entry key="name" value="payload.name"/>
            <entry key="category" value="payload.category"/>
            <entry key="tags" value="payload.tags"/>
            <entry key="author" value="payload.author"/>
            <entry key="sent" value="payload.sent"/>                
            <entry key="msg" value="payload.msg" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My splitter

```
public List<Article> split(Message<?> message) {
       
  return (List<Article>)message.getPayload();
```

}

Fix 1: Use of splitter to split Message with List  -> List of Messages

Fix 2 : I had no intention to set value for sent column (so no get/set for sent), but I created map including sent with payload.sent. This is the mistake.